# How do I remove torches upon death?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to find a way to set up some command blocks in bedrock edition so that when a player dies, torches are cleared from a certain area.

So far, I have this:

All chain command (cc) blocks and all always active, requiring no redstone

cc1: `/scoreboard objectives add hasDied dummy` (unconditional)

cc2: `/testfor @a[score_hasDied_min=1]` (conditional)

cc3: `/scoreboard players set @a hasDied 0`

cc4: `/fill -14 27 74 95 35 270 minecraft:air 0 destroy minecraft:torch 1`

Comment: This is close, the main issue left is capturing the actual death coordinate, and capturing that a death happened (unless you do mean to clear this specifically defined area, in which case all you need is to capture the death counter score going up)

Comment: @Unionhawk How would I go about doing that? I'm very unfamiliar with the commands but I did read about some of the syntax and such on the wikia.

Comment: hmm... The wiki says the deathCount objective type is java edition only, so I'm not actually sure how to do this in Bedrock. Sorry :/

Comment: It's alright. Thanks for pointing out the issue though!

Answer (score 1):

You have the `/fill` part correct but you need replace it like this `/fill -14 27 74 95 35 270 torch replace air`. Don't worry, it took me a while to figure this out myself. I do realize this might be to late to help, but better late then never.